# Is there a way to add borderRadius for pyramid highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I need to create a pyramid chart with some radius. I am using high charts with angular js for creating a pyramid chart but not able to add border-radius.

Need some suggestion on this.

Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hTn4.png

Comment: Have you considered using the 3D pyramid? You should be able to create a similar visibility output as a regular one with bordered-radius. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pyramid3d

Comment: Need to add border-radius only for edges. Attached an image for reference. Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible from the regular API options. You can report this idea as a feature request on the Highcharts Github issue channel: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues